# chrome.webRequest.onCompleted listener can't notice Facebook Messenger asking for an audi_clip.wav file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a simple chrome extension that could help people with impaired hearing to listen to audio_clips on Facebook Messenger.

[image]

I want to achieve something like so:

[image]

and so on... with python endpoint for speech recognition.

I have sos read about how to download mentioned files on Facebook Messenger and came to the conclusion that the only way is to monitor Network Tab in Developer Console in search for request containing audio_clip.wav files:

[image]

Such request after being clicked, indeed downloads the audio file.

So all seemed fine - I wanted to monitor traffic in search for matched urls but I can't seem to notice them...

Here is the code that does NOT work. It works for the first part though, it can correctly notice that we changed our interlocutor.

`manifest.json`

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Messenger audio2text",
    "description": "Converting messenger audio files to text when you can't listen them.",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "assets/ext-icon.png",
            "24": "assets/ext-icon.png",
            "32": "assets/ext-icon.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Messenger audio2text"
    },
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "webRequest"],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["foreground.js"],
            "matches": ["https://*.messenger.com/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

`foregorund.js`

```js
(() => {
    let currentInterlocutorId = 0;

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((obj, sender, response) => {
        const { type, value, interlocutorId, details } = obj;

        if (type === 'NEW') {
            currentInterlocutorId = interlocutorId;
            console.log('detected new interlocutor', interlocutorId);
        }

        if (type === 'REQUEST') {
            console.log('detected new request', details);
        }
    });
})();
```

`background.js`

```js
let currentTabId = 0;

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, tab) => {
    if (tab.url && tab.url.includes('messenger.com/t/')) {
        currentTabId = tabId;

        const interlocutorId = tab.url.split('/t/')[1];

        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            type: 'NEW',
            interlocutorId: interlocutorId,
        });
    }
});

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    (details) => {
        if (details.url.includes('audio_clip'))
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(currentTabId, {
                type: 'REQUEST',
                details: details,
            });
    },
    { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
    ['extraHeaders']
);
```

all help and tips would be much appreciated, I've spent some time on both Chrome and MDN docs but id didn't take me anywhere.

Comment: If you inspect that request you'll probably see it's served by the service worker, in which case there's no network request, so webRequest doesn't report anything, and the solution is to get the URL from the audio element in the content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Could you elaborate or link me to a source? I don't quite get what you mean in your proposed solution :/ If you mean the HTML element it unfortunately does not contain anything that could link such element to the correct audio clip.

Comment: In that case you can get the data by intercepting the method used by the site to create or play that audio element (e.g. the getter of HTMLMediaElement.prototype.src) in [page context](/a/9517879). Anyway, debug the code of the site in devtools and find how it obtains the audio.